# How should I format my .txt enum values?

Tags: mysql, enums

The table `test` from my database has a unique `ENUM` column. How should I format my .txt file in order to load data from it into the column?
This is how I'm doing it right now:

`text.txt:`

```
0
1
2
2
1
```

MySQL Script:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Data/test.txt' INTO TABLE test
```

DESCRIBE test

```
+-------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type              | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| enum  | enum('0','1','2') | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The output:

```
+------+
| enum |
+------+
|      |
|      |
|      |
|      |
| 1    |
+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The first (possible) bug is break line symbols, which is '\n' by default in unix systems. Check your file, a high probability that it is '\r\n', and add LINES TERMINATED clause -

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

The second bug - a file name, you wrote 'text.txt', but in LOAD DATA command you have used 'test.txt'.

[LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)